# Why do I get a KeyError in this Python code?

Tags: python, keyerror

I'm trying to run this code:

```
dictVar = {'PI': 3.14,
           25: "The Square of 5",
           "Weihan": "My Name"
           }

print("The value corresponding to the key " + str(3.14) + " is: " + dictVar[3.14])
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/KitKat#21266/Google Drive/Project Environment/From 0 to 1 Python Programming/Dictionary and If-Else.py", line 8, in <module>
    print("The value corresponding to the key " + str(3.14) + " is: " + dictVar[3.14])
KeyError: 3.14
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: Error is clear you have no key named `3.14`, you have `'PI'`, `25` and `"Weihan"`

Comment: Please take a moment to try out the code formatting tools here. We have `inline formatting` for very short pieces of code, and block formatting for chunks. Someone has re-formatted your post for you just now, but if you can do that, it saves someone that work. Thanks!

Comment: In dictVar 3.14 is the value corresponding to key 'PI'. It is not itself a key.

Comment: Hi I thought "PI": 3.14 where "PI" is the key @halfer sorry forgot the formatting.

Comment: Yes, "PI" is the key. So why are you trying to use "3.14" as the key?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i thought by inputting 3.14 it will tell me what the corresponding key is. I am following course material from a course on Udemy they didn't explain this part well the video cuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use keys that don't exist.

```
key = "PI"
print("The value corresponding to the key {0} is: {1}".format(key, dictVar[key]))
```

Comment: Hi with the above line of code i receive a TypeError: must be str, not float. (Do i have to str(3.14) in the dictironary?

Comment: @KitKatOverwatch My bad. Have edited. Forgot to add an `str()` call. You can't concatenate floats to strings directly.

Comment: Why are you even using `+` string concatenation in a `print` call? Just pass the data as separate args & let print handle the concatenation. `print("The value corresponding to the key", "'PI'", "is:", dictVar['PI'])`. Or use `format` if you want more control.

Comment: Good idea. Even better, I've used the formatting function.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print dictVar[3.14], but there is no key 3.14 in your dictionary.

Instead try using dictVar['PI']